# R- How do I use a lookup table containing threshold values that vary for different variables (columns) to replace values below those thresholds?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to streamline the process of auditing chemistry laboratory data. When we encounter data where an analyte is not detected I need to change the recorded result to a value equal to 1/2 of the level of detection (LOD) for the analytical method. I have LOD's contained within another dataframe to be used as a lookup table.

I have multiple columns representing data from different analytical tests, each with it's own unique LOD. Here's an example of the type of data I am working with:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble("Lab_ID" = as.character(seq(1,10,1)),
                 "Tributary" = c('sawmill','paint', 'herring', 'water',
                               'paint', 'sawmill', 'bolt', 'water',
                               'herring', 'sawmill'),
                 "date" = rep(as.POSIXct("2021-10-01 12:00:00"), 10),
                 "TP" = c(1.5,15.7,-2.3,7.6,0.1,45.6,12.2,-0.1,22.2,0.6),
                 "TN" = c(100.3,56.2,-10.5,0.4,-0.3,11.0,45.8,256.0,12.2,144.0),
                 "DOC" = c(56.0,120.3,-10.5,0.2,14.6,489.3,0.3,14.4,54.6,88.8))
dat


detect_level <- tibble("Parameter" = c('TP', 'TN', 'DOC'),
                          'LOD' = c(0.6, 11, 0.3)) %>% 
  mutate(halfLOD=LOD/2)
detect_level
```

I have poured over multiple other questions with a similar theme:

[Change values in multiple columns of a dataframe using a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633302/change-values-in-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-using-a-lookup-table)

[R - Match values from multiple columns in a data.frame to a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589637/r-match-values-from-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame-to-a-lookup-table).

[Replace values in multiple columns using different thresholds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933918/replace-values-in-multiple-columns-using-different-thresholds)

and gotten to a point where I have pivoted the data and split it out into a list of dataframes that are specific analytes:

```
dat %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = c('TP','TN','DOC')) %>% 
    arrange(name) %>% 
    split(.$name)
```

I have tried to apply a function using `map()`, however I cannot figure out how to integrate the values from the lookup table (`detect_level`) into my code. If someone could help me continue this pipe, or finish the process to achieve a final product `dat2` that should look like this I would appreciate it:

```
dat2 <- tibble("Lab_ID" = as.character(seq(1,10,1)),
              "Tributary" = c('sawmill','paint', 'herring', 'water',
                              'paint', 'sawmill', 'bolt', 'water',
                              'herring', 'sawmill'),
              "date" = rep(as.POSIXct("2021-10-01 12:00:00"), 10),
              "TP" = c(1.5,15.7,0.3,7.6,0.3,45.6,12.2,0.3,22.2,0.6),
              "TN" = c(100.3,56.2,5.5,5.5,5.5,11.0,45.8,256.0,12.2,144.0),
              "DOC" = c(56.0,120.3,0.15,0.15,14.6,489.3,0.3,14.4,54.6,88.8))

dat2
```

Another possibility would be from the closest similar question I have found is:

[Lookup multiple column from a single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67953198/lookup-multiple-column-from-a-single-table)

Here's a snippet of code that I have adapted from this question, however, if you run it you will see that where values exist that are not found in `detect_level` an `NA` is returned. Additionally, it does not appear to have worked for `$TN` or `$DOC`, even in cases when the `$LOD` value from `detect_level` was present.

```
dat %>% 
    mutate(across(all_of(unique(detect_level$Parameter)),
                  ~ {i1 <- detect_level$Parameter == cur_column()
                  detect_level$LOD[i1][match(., detect_level$LOD)]}))
```

I am not comfortable at all with the purrr language here and have only adapted this code from the question linked, so I would appreciate if this is the direction an answerer chooses, that they might comment code to explain briefly what is happening "under the hood".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(detect_level$Parameter), 
     ~ pmax(., detect_level$LOD[match(cur_column(), detect_level$Parameter)])))
```

---

For the updated case

```
dat %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(detect_level$Parameter), 
     ~ replace(., . < detect_level$LOD[match(cur_column(), 
    detect_level$Parameter)],detect_level$halfLOD[match(cur_column(), 
    detect_level$Parameter)])))
```

Comment: Wondering if you could take this a step further. I have edited `detect_level` to include values for 1/2 of the LOD, which is what I need to change the values to for those data in `dat` that are less than the LOD value. Can you suggest a way to replace values of `dat` below the `$LOD` value with `$halfLOD`?

Comment: Try the update in the solution